# Why is having a large page table bad?

Tags: virtual-memory, page-tables

In my lecturer's slides on Virtual Memory he has written that having a large page table is a problem, why would this be?

Answer (score 0):

A large page table is only bad when only a small number of entries in it are valid. If you're using the memory, you need a big enough table for all that you are using.